# Inserting a new record with DetailsView created dynamically with ITemplate

Tags: asp.net

I have been trying for hours but can't figure out why i can't succeed to insert a record using a DetailsView with field created dynamically using a ITemplate derived class, and SqlDataSource.

Here is the code used to create the templates:

```
public class DetailsViewTemplate : ITemplate
{
    private DataControlRowType templateType;
    private string columnNameFriendly;
    private string columnNameData;
    private Control control;
    private DetailsViewMode viewMode;
    public DetailsViewTemplate(DataControlRowType type, DetailsViewMode mode, string colNameFr, string colNameDt, Control con)
    {
        templateType = type;
        columnNameFriendly = colNameFr;
        columnNameData = colNameDt;
        control = con;
        viewMode = mode;
    }

    public void InstantiateIn(System.Web.UI.Control container)
    {
        switch (templateType)
        {
            case DataControlRowType.Header:
                {
                    Literal lc = new Literal();
                    lc.Text = columnNameFriendly;
                    container.Controls.Add(lc);
                    break;
                }
            case DataControlRowType.DataRow:
                {
                    Control field = control;
                    if (field.GetType() == typeof(Label))
                    {
                        Label lbl = (Label)control; // new Label();
                        if (viewMode != DetailsViewMode.Insert)
                            lbl.DataBinding += new EventHandler(this.lbl_DataBind);
                        container.Controls.Add(control);
                    }
                    else if (field.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
                    {
                        TextBox txt = (TextBox)control; // new TextBox();
                        if (viewMode != DetailsViewMode.Insert) 
                            txt.DataBinding += new EventHandler(this.txt_DataBind);
                        container.Controls.Add(control);
                    }
                    else if (field.GetType() == typeof(DropDownList))
                    {
                        DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)field;
                        if (viewMode != DetailsViewMode.Insert) 
                            ddl.DataBinding += new EventHandler(this.ddl_DataBind);
                        container.Controls.Add(control);
                    }
                    else if (field.GetType() == typeof(CheckBox))
                    {
                        CheckBox cbx = (CheckBox)control; // new CheckBox();
                        if (viewMode != DetailsViewMode.Insert)
                            cbx.DataBinding += new EventHandler(this.cbx_DataBind);
                        container.Controls.Add(control);
                    }
                    break;
                }
        }
    }

    private void txt_DataBind(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox txt = (TextBox)sender;
        DetailsView container = (DetailsView)txt.NamingContainer;
        if (((DataRowView)container.DataItem) != null)
            txt.Text = DataBinder.Eval(((DataRowView)container.DataItem), columnNameData).ToString();
        //txt.Font.Size = 7;
        txt.Font.Name = "Arial";
    }

    private void lbl_DataBind(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label lbl = (Label)sender;
        DetailsView container= (DetailsView)lbl.NamingContainer;
        if (((DataRowView)container.DataItem) != null)
            lbl.Text = DataBinder.Eval(((DataRowView)container.DataItem), columnNameData).ToString();
        //lbl.Font.Size = 7;
        lbl.Font.Name = "Arial";
    }

    private void ddl_DataBind(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)sender;
        DetailsView container = (DetailsView)ddl.NamingContainer;
        if (((DataRowView)container.DataItem) != null)
            ddl.SelectedValue = DataBinder.Eval(((DataRowView)container.DataItem), columnNameData).ToString();
        //ddl.Font.Size = 7;
        ddl.Font.Name = "Arial";
    }

    private void cbx_DataBind(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox cbx = (CheckBox)sender;
        DetailsView container = (DetailsView)cbx.NamingContainer;
        if (((DataRowView)container.DataItem) != null)
            cbx.Checked = (bool)DataBinder.Eval(((DataRowView)container.DataItem), columnNameData);
    }
}`
```

And here is the code that add the template fields to the DetailsView

```
            TextBox tb = new TextBox();

            TemplateField tf = new TemplateField();
            tf.HeaderTemplate = new DetailsViewTemplate(DataControlRowType.Header, DetailsViewDynAttachment.DefaultMode, fieldName, fieldName, new Label());
                tf.InsertItemTemplate = new DetailsViewTemplate(DataControlRowType.DataRow, DetailsViewDynAttachment.DefaultMode, fieldName, fieldName, tb);
```

DetailsViewDynAttachment.Fields.Add(tf);

The DetailsView mode is set to Insert, the InserCommand and oparameters list are defined BUT no matter what i try as soon as i use the built-in Insert command or call insert on the datasource all of my dynamically added controls seems to have disapeared after the postback and all the values lost ...

Note that the same code work in ReadOnly mode (with a SelectCommand set ...)
but can't figure why the fields seems not to get persisted in insert mode.

I searched for hours and tried everything i tought but can't find a solution to this ...
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

P.S.

The main issue here is that the dynamically added template fields do not persit after a postback. The DetailsView Fields and Rows is 1 (the command field) and all other dynamic fields are 'lost' (not persisted).
Moreover, although the ItemInserting is raised, it's (DetailsViewInsertEventArgs) e.Values count is 0. Values not persisted ... (?)

Why ?

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution ! So i thought to post it in case it might help anyone who want to do something similar.

There was a few problems in my prototype:

1- Have to use IBindableTemplate to achieve two-way binding. This class, adds to the InstantiateIn function used to implement the read binding, a function called ExtractValues which you must override to implement the binding the other way around (when inserting).

This functions is used to extracts the values from the dynamically created controls and returns them as an OrderedDictionary instance.

2- This is the tricky part: The dynamic template fields have to be created from within the Page_Init event. Otherwise the field will not be persisted. I will not risk to explain why although i think i understand ... Anyone ? ;-)

Here's the  updated version of the DetailsViewTemplate:IBindableTemplate class:

```
public class DetailsViewTemplate : IBindableTemplate
{
    private DataControlRowType templateType;
    private string columnNameFriendly;
    private string columnNameData;
    private Control control;
    private DetailsViewMode viewMode;

    //+=========================================================================+
    public DetailsViewTemplate(DataControlRowType type, DetailsViewMode mode, string colNameFr, string colNameDt, Control con)
    {
        templateType = type;
        columnNameFriendly = colNameFr;
        columnNameData = colNameDt;
        control = con;
        viewMode = mode;
    }
    //+=========================================================================+
    void ITemplate.InstantiateIn(System.Web.UI.Control container)
    {
        switch (templateType)
        {
            case DataControlRowType.Header:
            {
                Literal lc = new Literal();
                lc.Text = columnNameFriendly;
                container.Controls.Add(lc);
                break;
            }
            case DataControlRowType.DataRow:
            {
                if (control.GetType() == typeof(Label))
                {
                    Label lbl = (Label)control; // new Label();
                    if (viewMode != DetailsViewMode.Insert)
                        lbl.DataBinding += new EventHandler(this.lbl_DataBind);
                    container.Controls.Add(control);
                }
                else if (control.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
                {
                    TextBox txt = (TextBox)control; // new TextBox();
                    if (viewMode != DetailsViewMode.Insert)
                        txt.DataBinding += new EventHandler(this.txt_DataBind);
                    container.Controls.Add(control);
                }
                else if (control.GetType() == typeof(DropDownList))
                {
                    DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)control;
                    if (viewMode != DetailsViewMode.Insert)
                        ddl.DataBinding += new EventHandler(this.ddl_DataBind);
                    container.Controls.Add(control);
                }
                else if (control.GetType() == typeof(CheckBox))
                {
                    CheckBox cbx = (CheckBox)control; // new CheckBox();
                    if (viewMode != DetailsViewMode.Insert)
                        cbx.DataBinding += new EventHandler(this.cbx_DataBind);
                    container.Controls.Add(control);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    //+=========================================================================+
    private void txt_DataBind(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox txt = (TextBox)sender;
        DetailsView container = (DetailsView)txt.NamingContainer;
        if (((DataRowView)container.DataItem) != null)
            txt.Text = DataBinder.Eval(((DataRowView)container.DataItem), columnNameData).ToString();
        //txt.Font.Size = 7;
        txt.Font.Name = "Arial";
    }
    //+=========================================================================+
    private void lbl_DataBind(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label lbl = (Label)sender;
        DetailsView container = (DetailsView)lbl.NamingContainer;
        if (((DataRowView)container.DataItem) != null)
            lbl.Text = DataBinder.Eval(((DataRowView)container.DataItem), columnNameData).ToString();
        //lbl.Font.Size = 7;
        lbl.Font.Name = "Arial";
    }
    //+=========================================================================+
    private void ddl_DataBind(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)sender;
        DetailsView container = (DetailsView)ddl.NamingContainer;
        if (((DataRowView)container.DataItem) != null)
            ddl.SelectedValue = DataBinder.Eval(((DataRowView)container.DataItem), columnNameData).ToString();
        //ddl.Font.Size = 7;
        ddl.Font.Name = "Arial";
    }
    //+=========================================================================+
    private void cbx_DataBind(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox cbx = (CheckBox)sender;
        DetailsView container = (DetailsView)cbx.NamingContainer;
        if (((DataRowView)container.DataItem) != null)
            cbx.Checked = (bool)DataBinder.Eval(((DataRowView)container.DataItem), columnNameData);
    }
    //+=========================================================================+
    IOrderedDictionary IBindableTemplate.ExtractValues(Control container)
    {
        OrderedDictionary dict = new OrderedDictionary();
        if (control.GetType() == typeof(Label))
        {
            Label lb = (Label)FindControlRecursive(container, columnNameData);
            if (lb != null)
                dict[columnNameData] = lb.Text;
        }
        else if (control.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
        {
            TextBox tb = (TextBox)FindControlRecursive(container, columnNameData);
            if (tb != null)
                dict[columnNameData] = tb.Text;
        }
        else if (control.GetType() == typeof(CheckBox))
        {
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)FindControlRecursive(container, columnNameData);
            if (cb != null)
                dict[columnNameData] = cb.Checked;
        }
        else if (control.GetType() == typeof(DropDownList))
        {
            DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)FindControlRecursive(container, columnNameData);
            if (ddl != null)
                dict[columnNameData] = ddl.SelectedValue;
        }
        return dict;
    }
    //+=========================================================================+
    private Control FindControlRecursive(Control ctlRoot, string sControlId)
    {
        // if this control is the one we are looking for, break from the recursion
        // and return the control.
        if (ctlRoot.ID == sControlId)
        {
            return ctlRoot;
        }
        // loop the child controls of this parent control and call recursively.
        foreach (Control ctl in ctlRoot.Controls)
        {
            Control ctlFound = FindControlRecursive(ctl, sControlId);
            // if we found the control, return it.
            if (ctlFound != null)
            {
                return ctlFound;
            }
        }
        // we never found the control so just return null.
        return null;
    }
    //+=========================================================================+
}
```

So, what is this useful for ?
Using this mechanism, you can create a DetailsView for any table record for which you can get a SqlConnection. And with some GetSchema magic. you can write code to edit any table record not known at design time.

That was the goal of my 'quest' ;-)

Hope it may be useful for some ...
Happy New year ! (dec. 31st @ 5:14 PM)

Comment: I have problem with dynamic edit template but with FormView. I can't get the new values out of FormViewUpdateEventArgs e

   protected void FormView1_ItemUpdating(object sender, FormViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {

        EditFormView.UpdateCommand = "UPDATE " + UniqueTable + " SET bla_Opis='" + e.NewValues["bla_Opis"] + "'  WHERE " + PrimaryKey + "=" + ident;
        EditFormView.Update();
        //EditFormView.DataBind();
    }
I think the problem is that I override the new values on page_init with old ones. Could you please post you page init method?